# Wordpress frontend submit form doesn't save selected categories and post description post_meta

Tags: php, wordpress, file-upload

I have one week working with a new Wordpress tube theme and I have created frontend submit form for the users with some limitation options in redux framework.This is first time working with file uploader for me.

```
<?php
if( !defined('ABSPATH') ) exit;
if( !class_exists('Tubemobile_ShortcodeSubmitVideo') ){
    class Tubemobile_ShortcodeSubmitVideo {
        function __construct() {
            add_action('init', array($this,'add_shortcodes'));
            add_action('wp_ajax_awpt_submit_video', array($this,'action_form'));
            add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_awpt_submit_video', array($this,'action_form'));
        }
        function add_shortcodes(){
            add_shortcode('upload', array($this,'videotube_upload'));
        }
        function videotube_upload( $attr, $content = null){
            global $awpt;
            global $post;
            $html = null;
            extract(shortcode_atts(array(
                'vcategory' =>  'on',
                'vtag'      =>  'on',
                'cat_exclude'   =>  '',
                'cat_include'   =>  '',
                'cat_orderby'       =>  'name',
                'cat_order' =>  'DESC'
            ), $attr));
            $video_type = isset( $awpt['video-type'] ) ? $awpt['video-type'] : null;
            if( !is_array( $video_type ) ){
                $video_type = (array)$video_type;
            }
            $submit_roles = isset( $awpt['submit_roles'] ) ? (array)$awpt['submit_roles'] : 'author';
            if( count( $submit_roles ) == 1 ){
                $submit_roles = (array)$submit_roles;
            }
            //print_r($submit_roles);
            ### 0 is not allow guest, 1 is only register.
            $submit_permission = isset( $awpt['submit_permission'] ) ? $awpt['submit_permission'] : 0;
            $user_id = get_current_user_id();
            $current_user_role = awpt_get_user_role( $user_id );
            ### Check if Admin does not allow Visitor submit the video.
            if( $submit_permission == 0 && !$user_id ){
                $html .= '<a class="formLink" _form="login" href="/login" id="show_login"><i class="icon"><i class="fa fa-sign-in" aria-hidden="true"></i></i> <span>Login</span></a>';

                //$html .= '[login]';
            }
            //elseif( $submit_permission == 0 && !in_array( $current_user_role, $submit_roles) && $current_user_role != 'administrator'){
            elseif( $submit_permission == 0 && !in_array( $current_user_role, $submit_roles)){
                $html .= '
                    <div class="notifications "><div data-ntime="0" class="notifications__item notifications__item-error">'.__('You don\'t have the right permission to access this feature.','tubemobile').'</div></div>
                ';
            }
            else{
                $categories_html = null;
                $category_array = array(
                    'hide_empty'=>0,
                    'order' =>  $cat_order,
                    'orderby'   =>  $cat_orderby,
                );
                if( !empty( $cat_exclude ) ){
                    $cat_exclude = explode(",", $cat_exclude);
                    if( is_array( $cat_exclude ) ){
                        $category_array['exclude']  = $cat_exclude;
                    }
                }
                if( !empty( $cat_include ) ){
                    $cat_include = explode(",", $cat_include);
                    if( is_array( $cat_include ) ){
                        $category_array['include']  = $cat_include;
                    }
                }

                $categories = get_terms('category', $category_array);
                 if ( !empty( $categories ) && !is_wp_error( $categories ) ){
                    $categories_html .= '<select id="pre-selected-options" multiple="multiple">';
                    foreach ( $categories as $category ){
                        $categories_html .= '<option value="'.$category->term_id.'">'.$category->name.'</option>';
                    }
                    $categories_html .= '</select>';
                 }
                $html .= '
                <div class="holder" style="margin-top:0;">
                    <form role="form" action="" method="post" id="awpt-submit-video-form" enctype="multipart/form-data" style="padding:0;">
                      <div class="field_form post_title">
                        <label for="post_title">'.__('Video Title','tubemobile').'</label>
                        <span class="label label-danger">'.__('*','tubemobile').'</span>
                        <input type="text" class="input form-control" name="post_title" id="post_title">
                        <span class="help-block"></span>
                      </div>
                      <div class="field_form post_content">
                        <label for="post_content">'.__('Video Description','tubemobile').'</label>
                        ';
                        if( $awpt['submit_editor'] == 1 ){
                            $html .= awpt_get_editor('', 'post_content', 'post_content');
                        }
                        else{
                            $html .= '<div class="textarea_comment"><textarea name="post_content" id="post_content" class="textarea form-control" rows="3"></textarea></div>';
                        }
                      $html .= '<span class="help-block"></span>';
                      $html .= '</div>
                      <div class="field_form video-types">
                        <label for="post_title">'.__('Video Type','tubemobile').'</label>
                        <span class="label label-danger">'.__('*','tubemobile').'</span>';
                        if( in_array( 'videolink', $video_type ) ){
                            $html .= '
                                <div class="radio">
                                    <input type="radio" value="video_link_type" name="chb_video_type">'.__('Link','tubemobile').'
                                </div>
                            ';
                        }
                        if( in_array( 'embedcode', $video_type ) ){
                            $html .= '
                                <div class="radio">
                                    <input type="radio" value="embed_code_type" name="chb_video_type">'.__('Embed Code','tubemobile').'
                                </div>
                            ';
                        }
                        if( in_array( 'videofile', $video_type ) ){
                            $html .= '
                                <div class="radio">
                                    <input checked type="radio" value="file_type" name="chb_video_type">'.__('Upload file','tubemobile').'
                                </div>
                            ';
                        }
                      $html .= '
                      </div>';
                      if( in_array( 'videolink', $video_type ) ){
                        $html .= '
                          <div class="field_form video_url video-type video_link_type">
                            <label for="video_url">'.__('Video Link','tubemobile').'</label>
                            <span class="label label-danger">'.__('*','tubemobile').'</span>
                            <input type="text" class="input form-control" name="video_url" id="video_url" placeholder="Example: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X6pQ-pNSnRE">
                            <span class="help-block"></span>
                          </div>
                        ';
                      }
                      if( in_array( 'embedcode', $video_type ) ){
                        $html .= '
                          <div class="textarea_comment field_form embed_code_type video-type embed_code_type" style="display:none;">
                            <label for="video_url">'.__('Embed Code','tubemobile').'</label>
                            <span class="label label-danger">'.__('*','tubemobile').'</span>
                            <textarea class="form-control" name="embed_code" id="embed_code"></textarea>
                            <span class="help-block"></span>
                          </div>
                        ';
                      }
                      if( in_array( 'videofile', $video_type ) ){
                        $html .= '
                          <div class="field_form video_file video-type file_type" style="display:none;">
                            <label for="video_url">'.__('Video File','tubemobile').'</label>
                            <span class="label label-danger">'.__('*','tubemobile').'</span>
                            <input type="file" type="text" class="form-control" name="video_file" id="video_file">
                            <span class="help-block"></span>
                          </div>
                        ';
                      }
                      $html .= '
                      <div class="field_form video_thumbnail">
                        <label for="video_url">'.__('Video Preview Image','tubemobile').'</label>
                        <span class="label label-info">'.__('This image is required if you submit an embed code or a video file.','tubemobile').'</span>
                        <input type="file" type="text" class="form-control" name="video_thumbnail" id="video_thumbnail">
                        <span class="help-block"></span>

                      </div>';
                      if( $vtag == 'on' ):
                          $html .= '<div class="field_form video-tag">
                            <label for="key">'.__('Video Tag','tubemobile').'</label>
                            <input type="text" class="input form-control" name="post_tag" id="post_tag">
                          </div>';
                      endif;
                      if( $vcategory == 'on' ):
                        $html .= '<div class="field_form categories-video">
                            <label for="category">'.__('Category','tubemobile').'</label>';
                            $html .= $categories_html;
                          $html .= '</div>';
                      endif;
                      $html .= '<div class="btn_block"><input type="submit" class="input btn-primary""></div>
                      <img id="loading" style="display:none;">
                      <input type="hidden" name="current_page" value="'.$post->ID.'">
                      <input type="hidden" name="action" value="awpt_submit_video">
                      '.wp_nonce_field('submit_video_act','submit_video',true,false).'

                    </form></div>
                ';

            }
            return do_shortcode( $html );
        }
        function action_form(){
            global $awpt;
            $videosize = isset( $awpt['videosize'] ) ? (int)$awpt['videosize'] : 10;
            $post_title = wp_filter_nohtml_kses( $_POST['post_title'] );
            $video_url = isset( $_POST['video_url'] ) ? trim( $_POST['video_url'] ) : null;
            $embed_code = isset( $_POST['embed_code'] ) ? trim( $_POST['embed_code'] ) : null;
            $video_file = isset( $_FILES['video_file'] ) ? $_FILES['video_file'] : null;
            $post_content = wp_filter_nohtml_kses( $_POST['video_description'] );
            //$post_content = isset( $_POST['awpt_desc'] ) ? trim( $_POST['awpt_desc'] ) : null;
            $chb_video_type = isset( $_POST['chb_video_type'] ) ? $_POST['chb_video_type'] : null;
            $video_thumbnail = isset( $_FILES['video_thumbnail'] ) ? $_FILES['video_thumbnail'] : null;
            $post_tag = isset( $_POST['post_tag'] ) ? wp_filter_nohtml_kses( $_POST['post_tag'] ) : null;
            $video_category = isset( $_POST['video_category'] ) ? $_POST['video_category'] : null;
            $user_id = get_current_user_id() ? get_current_user_id() : $awpt['submit_assigned_user'];
            $post_status = $awpt['submit_status'] ? $awpt['submit_status'] : 'pending';
            $layout = isset( $_POST['layout'] ) ? $_POST['layout'] : 'small';


            if( !$post_title ){
                echo json_encode(array(
                    'resp'  =>  'error',
                    'message'   =>  __('Video Title is required','tubemobile'),
                    'element_id'    =>  'post_title'
                ));exit;
            }
            /*
            if( !$post_content ){
                echo json_encode(array(
                    'resp'  =>  'error',
                    'message'   =>  __('Video Description is required','tubemobile'),
                    'element_id'    =>  'post_content'
                ));exit;
            }
        */
            if( !$chb_video_type ){
                echo json_encode(array(
                    'resp'  =>  'error',
                    'message'   =>  __('Video Type is required','tubemobile'),
                    'element_id'    =>  'chb_video_type'
                ));exit;
            }

            switch ($chb_video_type) {
                case 'video_link_type':
                    if( !$video_url ){
                        echo json_encode(array(
                            'resp'  =>  'error',
                            'message'   =>  __('Video Link is required','tubemobile'),
                            'element_id'    =>  'video_url'
                        ));exit;
                    }
                    if( !wp_oembed_get( $video_url ) ){
                        echo json_encode(array(
                            'resp'  =>  'error',
                            'message'   =>  __('The link does not support.','tubemobile'),
                            'element_id'    =>  'video_url'
                        ));exit;
                    }
                break;

                case 'embed_code_type':
                    if( !$embed_code ){
                        echo json_encode(array(
                            'resp'  =>  'error',
                            'message'   =>  __('Embed Code is required','tubemobile'),
                            'element_id'    =>  'embed_code'
                        ));exit;
                    }
                    if( apply_filters( 'awpt_submitform_thumbnail_required' , true) === true ):
                        if( !$video_thumbnail ){
                            echo json_encode(array(
                                'resp'  =>  'error',
                                'message'   =>  __('Video Preview Image is required','tubemobile'),
                                'element_id'    =>  'video_thumbnail'
                            ));exit;
                        }
                        if( !awpt_check_file_allowed( $video_thumbnail, 'image' ) ){
                            echo json_encode(array(
                                'resp'  =>  'error',
                                'message'   =>  __('Video Preview Image type is invalid','tubemobile'),
                                'element_id'    =>  'video_thumbnail'
                            ));exit;
                        }
                    endif;
                break;
                default:
                    if( !$video_file ){
                        echo json_encode(array(
                            'resp'  =>  'error',
                            'message'   =>  __('Video File is required.','tubemobile'),
                            'element_id'    =>  'video_file'
                        ));exit;
                    }
                    if( !awpt_check_file_allowed( $video_file, 'video' ) ){
                        echo json_encode(array(
                            'resp'  =>  'error',
                            'message'   =>  __('Video File format is invalid.','tubemobile'),
                            'element_id'    =>  'video_file'
                        ));exit;
                    }
                    if( !awpt_check_file_size_allowed($video_file) ){
                        echo json_encode(array(
                            'resp'  =>  'error',
                            'message'   =>  __('The video size must be less than ' . $videosize . 'MB','tubemobile'),
                            'element_id'    =>  'video_file'
                        ));exit;
                    }
                    if( apply_filters( 'awpt_submitform_thumbnail_required' , true) === true ):
                        if( !$video_thumbnail ){
                            echo json_encode(array(
                                'resp'  =>  'error',
                                'message'   =>  __('Video Preview Image is required','tubemobile'),
                                'element_id'    =>  'video_thumbnail'
                            ));exit;
                        }
                        if( !awpt_check_file_allowed( $video_thumbnail, 'image' ) ){
                            echo json_encode(array(
                                'resp'  =>  'error',
                                'message'   =>  __('Video Preview Image type is invalid','tubemobile'),
                                'element_id'    =>  'video_thumbnail'
                            ));exit;
                        }
                    endif;
                break;
            }

            /**
             * Error handler
             * @since Videotube V2.2.7
             */
            $errors = new WP_Error();
            $errors =   apply_filters( 'do_ajax_submit_video_errors' , $errors, $_POST );

            if ( ! empty( $errors->errors ) ) {
                echo json_encode(array(
                    'resp'  =>  'error',
                    'message'   =>  $errors->get_error_message(),
                    'element_id'    =>  $errors->get_error_code()
                ));exit;
            }

            $postarr = array(
                'post_title'    =>  $post_title,
                'post_content'  =>  $post_content,
                'post_type' =>  'post',
                'post_author'   =>  $user_id,
                'post_status'   =>  $post_status,
                'comment_status'    =>  'open'
            );

            $postarr    =   apply_filters( 'awpt_submit_data_args' , $postarr );

            $post_id = wp_insert_post($postarr, true);

            if ( is_wp_error( $post_id ) ){
                echo json_encode(array(
                    'resp'  =>  'error',
                    'message'   =>  $post_id->get_error_message()
                ));exit;
            }

            ###  update meta
            if( $layout ){
                update_post_meta( $post_id , 'layout', $layout);
            }
            if( $video_url ){
                update_post_meta( $post_id , 'video_url', $video_url);
            }
            elseif ( $embed_code){
                update_post_meta( $post_id , 'video_url', $embed_code);
            }
            else{
                ### Upload files.
                if( function_exists('awpt_insert_attachment') ){
                    awpt_insert_attachment('video_file', $post_id, false, 'video_file');
                    update_post_meta( $post_id , 'video_type', 'files');
                }
            }
            ### Preview image
            if( $video_thumbnail ){
                ### Upload files.
                if( function_exists('awpt_insert_attachment') ){
                    awpt_insert_attachment('video_thumbnail', $post_id, true);
                }
            }
            ### update term
            if( $post_tag ){
                wp_set_post_terms($post_id, $post_tag,'tag',true);
            }
            if( $video_category ){
                wp_set_post_terms($post_id, $video_category,'category',true);
            }
            do_action('awpt_save_post',$post_id);
            if( $post_status != 'publish' ){
                $redirect_to = $awpt['submit_redirect_to'] ? get_permalink( $awpt['submit_redirect_to'] ) : NULL;
                if( empty( $redirect_to ) ){
                    echo json_encode(array(
                        'resp'  =>  'success',
                        'message'   =>  __('Congratulation, Your submit is waiting for approval.','tubemobile'),
                        'post_id'   =>  $post_id,
                    ));exit;
                }
                else{
                    echo json_encode(array(
                        'resp'  =>  'success',
                        'message'   =>  __('Congratulation, Your submit is waiting for approval.','tubemobile'),
                        'post_id'   =>  $post_id,
                        'redirect_to'   =>  $redirect_to
                    ));exit;
                }
            }
            else{
                echo json_encode(array(
                    'resp'  =>  'publish',
                    'message'   =>  __('Congratulation, Your submit is published.','tubemobile'),
                    'post_id'   =>  $post_id,
                    'redirect_to'   =>  get_permalink( $post_id )
                ));exit;
            }
        }
    }
    new Tubemobile_ShortcodeSubmitVideo();
}
```

When I submit the button many things working fine.Its saving the video file  to the post, so title and video is okay and everything works fine except video categories and tags.

I have only 2 issues.

1. I need to get the video description as a custom field.
2. Video Categories are not saving.

Comment: What have you already tried yourself to do this? Please review [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). Stack Overflow is not a coding service. You are expected to research your issue and make a good attempt to write the code yourself before posting. If you get stuck on something *specific*, come back and include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and a summary of what you tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was in categories name attribute because it requires array so I changed `name="category"` to `name="category[]"` and it worked fine I changed tag to post_tag and now its saving both tags and categories.

the problem on the video description was the same, a mistake on the name attribute now everything is working fine.

Answer (score 2):

For video descrption in post meta :

```
 $postarr = array(
            'post_title'    =>  $post_title,
            'post_content'  =>  $post_title,// set any value here other wise it will stop inserting your post
            'post_type' =>  'post',
            'post_author'   =>  $user_id,
            'post_status'   =>  $post_status,
            'comment_status'    =>  'open'
        );

        $postarr    =   apply_filters( 'awpt_submit_data_args' , $postarr );

        $post_id = wp_insert_post($postarr, true);
        //this will update your post meta 
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'videoDescrption', $post_content);
        //below line is write to give you the understanding that you need to pass it as a array
        $arrayoftags=$video_tag;
        wp_set_post_terms( $post_id, $arrayoftags);
        //below line is write to give you the understanding that you need to pass it as a array
        $arrayoftags = $video_category;
        wp_set_post_categories( $post_id, $arrayofcategories );
```

**Important note :**

For post meta : Remember if you are not having the add_meta function for this it will be not visible in your admin section but you can check the value in your database in postmeta table.

For tag : It is essential to have array in tags. I have put the comment above the code.

For categories : It is essential to have array in categories. I have put the comment above the code.

For Post content : post content cannot be null other wise it will stop creating your post.

**Read my each and every comment mentioned in the code.**

Comment: thanks for the reply Im reading carefully as you see I changed $post_content below $post_content = wp_filter_nohtml_kses( $_POST['video_description'] ); however Im going to test it right now thanks again

Comment: So, created a new line in action_form() like `$video_description = isset( $_POST['video_description'] ) ? trim( $_POST['video_description'] ) : null;` than in postarr I added a value to the post_content like `'post_content' => $video_description,` also I added a new line in save_post function:    `if( $video_description ){
    update_post_meta( $post_id , 'video_description', $video_description);
   }` No luck now it doesn't save post and submit button doesn't respond so I see loading image and no more redirects to the success page.

Comment: I changed also name attributes in html from post_content to video_description but still not posting anything it remains on the actual page.

Comment: check do you getting the value in $video_description and is $post_id or not?if you are getting than pass true in updatpost meta update_post_meta( $post_id , 'video_description', $video_description,true);

Comment: however when I change postarr line to $_post_content again and additionally for the video description I did the same steps of the embed_code which is working fine but still it doesn't update the post meta into database

Comment: did you pass true in the  paramater?

Comment: 1. `$video_description = isset( $_POST['video_description'] ) ? trim( $_POST['video_description'] ) : null;` 2. `if( $video_description ){
    update_post_meta( $post_id , 'video_description', $video_description);
   }` 3. `$html .= '<div class="textarea_comment"><textarea name="video_descripion" id="video_description" class="textarea form-control" rows="3"></textarea></div>';` that all I kept also the post_content true so it will post an empty post_content but the only thing that it doesn't save or update description post_meta

Comment: So in your text area  you wish to display that content?

Comment: yes the full code above as you see has other custom field options which are working fine I did exactly the same as embed_code field in the code but it doesn't add it as post meta check this screen https://s26.postimg.org/js7cjwdp5/Schermata_2017-09-20_alle_12.34.46.png I must have there also the video_description with the value

Comment: can you check with database please as i mentioned?

Comment: Yes I checked in phpmyadmin too but there is nothing.

Comment: I just edited my question and I added the final code with additional changes thanks for your time!

Comment: Also for the categories and tags I think Im doing anything wrong after moving it from custom post type to normal Wordpress post.